# Estimating a Probability Density Function for the Mean of a Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, estimation, density-function, bayes-theorem

I have been presented with the following problem:

1. I don't know the mean of a Gaussian random variable;
2. Will consider this mean as another random variable (M). M can take the values $Z_1$ with probability $p$ and $Z_2$ with probability $(1-p)$, where $p ∈ (0, 1)$.
3. I know that $Z_1 \sim N(μ_1, σ_1)$ and $Z_2 \sim N(μ_2, σ_2)$.
4. **What is the density of M?**

By the Law of Total Probability I got to this expression:
$$
P(M) = P(M|Z_1)P(Z_1) + P(M|Z_2)P(Z_2)
$$

Can I consider $P(M)$, as presented above, as the density of M?

*And, does $P(M|Z_1)$ represent the density of the Normal distribution with mean $μ_1$ and variance $σ_1$?*

I am afraid I am mixing some statistical concepts here, I really appreciate if you could enlighten me, thank you!

Comment: What you mean with estimate? Are you going to use any data to find some estimation? Could you clarify your problem more cerafelly? I can not understad what are you looking for? Is this just the density of $M$

Comment: I have changed it now, I hope it's clearer! I don't want to find the mean, I just want to find its probability density function.

Comment: Well, what I understand is that you suppose there exists some Gaussian random variable, say $M$, with the conditions that you say. All you want to know is the pdf of it....am I right?

Comment: Yes! But can I already consider M as a gaussian (given the information presented)?

Comment: Well, is this a question from some textbook or some reasearch?

Comment: If this is from a textbook, then you should write properly the question with the analogous reference...

Comment: It is not from a published textbook, it's related to an academic assignment. Between research and textbook I thought it would be closer, just that :)

Comment: Well, could I have a look in this kind of textbook? Is it somewhere free? or not?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $P(M)$ is not a density it's a probability.

With 2. we have $M = p*Z_1 + (1-p)*Z_2$ where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are Gaussian distributions.

So we can say that $M$ is a linear combination of two normal distribution.

This gives us directly the distribution of $M$ which is going to be : $$M∼N(p*μ_1+(1-p)*μ_2, p^2*σ_1^2+(1-p)^2*σ_2^2)$$

Now it's easy to have the density of $M$ which is going to be:
$$f_M(m) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2*\pi)σ_m}* \exp(-\frac{(m-μ_m)^2}{2σ_m^2})$$ where we have :

$μ_m = p*μ_1+(1-p)*μ_2 $
$σ_m^2 = p^2*σ_1^2+(1-p)^2*σ_2^2$

EDIT:
$Z_1$ and $Z_2$ should be independent.
$Z_1∼N(μ_1,σ_1^2)$ and $Z_2∼N(μ_2,σ_2^2)$

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one question, when you say that M=p*Z1+(1-p)*Z2, are you applying the law of total probability?

Comment: @SusyA. Ithink it's by definition since you said that M takes $Z_1$ with a probability of $p$ and $Z_2$ with $1-p$

Comment: @SusyA. If this answers your question, please check the mark

Comment: Actually, I've been thinking about this question and what do you mean with "by definition" when you define M as the sum of two normal distributions? Thank you once more!